# JS Array не работает push

Tags: javascript, массивы, json

Должен добавлять значения типа

```
sendBtn.onclick = () => {
    msgList.messages.push({'message': sendInput.value, 'isHidden': false});
```

в `msgList = {'messages': []}; //[];`

Но ничего не добавляется

В идеали бы даже без messages иметь массив. Недавно все работало именно так, не пойму что случилось, когда код не менял...

нашел проблему:

```
function addMessage(msg) {
    newLi = document.createElement('li');
    newLi.textContent = msg;
    newLi.className += 'msg-area__msg-' + --msgList.messages.length;
    list.appendChild(newLi);
    newLi.scrollIntoView();
}
```

--msgList.messages.length - именно `--` портит код и создает проблему. Но **КАК** это происходит, почему!?

Comment: Какие ошибки в консоли?

Comment: Могу ошибаться, код представлен не полностью, но попробуйте объявить msgList.messages как массив msgList.messages=[]

Comment: Скобка забыта в конце... `false}));`

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko никаких, просто ничего не добавляется.

Comment: Попробуйте в обработчик добавить вывод в консоль содержимое `msgList` до и после push()'a

Comment: @Jigius делал - ничего не меняется, просто нет реакции на пуш!

Comment: в начало обработчика  добавить `console.log(msgList.messages.constructor, msgList.messages.__proto__.constructor, msgList.messages.push, msgList.messages.__proto__.push);` Что выводит?

Comment: @Jigius `ƒ Array() { [native code] } ƒ Array() { [native code] } ƒ push() { [native code] } ƒ push() { [native code] }` и до, и после пуш-добавления выводит это.

Comment: Покажите нам `sendBtn`

Comment: `sendBtn.onclick = () => {
    msgList.messages.push({'message': sendInput.value, 'isHidden': false});}` фигурную скобку в конце добавьте. А если она у вас в коде есть, то исправьте вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: нашел проблему:

    function addMessage(msg) {
     newLi = document.createElement('li');
     newLi.textContent = msg;
     newLi.className += 'msg-area__msg-' + --msgList.messages.length;
     list.appendChild(newLi);
     newLi.scrollIntoView();
    }

--msgList.messages.length - именно `--` портит код и создает проблему. Но **КАК** это происходит, почему!?

Comment: @CodeGust, `--msgList.messages.length;` уменьшает длину массива, удаляя конечный в нем элемент. Используйте например, такую конструкцию, вместо прежней:  `(msgList.messages.length - 1).toString();`

Comment: @Jigius спасибо! не думал, что length можно ставить вручную другим.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> newLi.className += 'msg-area__msg-' + --msgList.messages.length;
> ```

Ну сам же написал в вопросе, что этот код кривой... Надо так.

```
newLi.className += 'msg-area__msg-' + (msgList.messages.length - 1);
```

А ещё не понимаю, какой вообще смысл уникальные классы вешать. Может тогда уж полезнее будет id использовать?

Comment: спасибо! хотя, собирался уже удалять вопрос, так как его суть - ошибка кода (модератор может удалять ;) ). Классы - для БЭМ и stylus msg-area /*css code*/ &__msg-3 /*css code*/ &__msg9 /*code ......*/. Но да, верно заметили, в данном слчае в моем коде вообще не нужны классы для li - спасибо))